# change main form controls by trigger event inside canvas

Tags: wpf

I am currently working on a project that required me to use a canvas in order to draw rectangles around specific places in a picture (to mark places)

Each rectangle (actually "rectangle" since it is also a custom class that I created by inheriting from the `Grid` class and contain a rectangle object) contains properties and data about the marked place inside the picture.
my main form contains controls such as `TextBox` ,`DropDownLists` and etc.

Now what I am trying to do is that for each time I am clicking on the "rectangle" object the main form controls will be filled with the object data.
I do not have access to those controls from the canvas class.

this code is inside the costume canvas class to add the object into the canvas:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown( MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
   if(e.ClickCount==2)
    {
      testTi = new TiTest();
      base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
      startPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
      testTi.MouseLeftButtonDown += testTi_MouseLeftButtonDown;
      Canvas.SetLeft(testTi, e.GetPosition(this).X);
      Canvas.SetTop(testTi, e.GetPosition(this).X);
      this.Children.Add(testTi);
   }
}
```

and by clicking an object that is placed inside the canvas i want to get the information.
for now just want to make sure i am getting the right object with a simple messagebox

```
void testTi_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(sender.GetType().ToString());         
  }
```

this is my costume "Rectangle" class

```
class TiTest:Grid
{

    private Label tiNameLabel;
    private Rectangle tiRectangle;
    private String SomeText = string.Empty;
    private String version = "1.0";
    private String application = "CRM";
    private String CRID = "NNN";

    public String SomeText1
    {
        get { return SomeText; }
        set { SomeText = value; }
    }

    public Rectangle TiRectangle
    {
        get { return tiRectangle; }
        set { tiRectangle = value; }
    }
    public Label TiNameLabel
    {
        get { return tiNameLabel; }
        set { tiNameLabel = value; }
    }

    public TiTest()
    {
        this.SomeText = "Hello World!!";
        this.TiNameLabel = new Label
            {
                Content = "Test Item",
                VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top,
                HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
            };
        TiRectangle = new Rectangle
          {
              Stroke = Brushes.Red,
              StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 3 },//Brushes.LightBlue,
              StrokeThickness = 2,
              Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
              Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 111, 0))
          };
        Background= Brushes.Aqua;
        Opacity = 0.5;
        this.Children.Add(this.tiNameLabel);
        this.Children.Add(this.tiRectangle);


    }

}
```

is there any way to access the main form controls from the costume canvas class or by the costume rectangle class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sidenote - Why did you create a custom rectangle by inheriting from `Grid` class and not [`Shape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx) class or [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx) class itself?

Comment: hi,
because i needed a way to add text label to the marking object.there is no way to add label to rectangle,so i used a grid so i can add to that grid children (label and rectangle) the rectangle size will actually be the grid size.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your main window be binded to a singletone `ViewModel` holding the properties of the rectangles.

ViewModel

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Singletone

    private static MainWindowViewModel _instance;

    private MainWindowViewModel()
    {

    }

    public static MainWindowViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new MainWindowViewModel();

            return _instance;
        }
    } 

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private string _someInfo;
    public string SomeInfo
    {
        get 
        {
            return _someInfo; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (_someInfo != value)
            {
                _someInfo = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeInfo"));
            }


        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

In main window xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeInfo}"/>
```

Also set the view model as your main window data context (in main window constructor for exmaple)

```
this.DataContext = MainWindowViewModel.Instance;
```

Finally, from where you handle the click event of the rectangles (`testTi_MouseLeftButtonDown`), access the `MainWindowViewModel` instance and set it's properties accordingly.

```
MainWindowViewModel.Instance.SomeInfo = myRectangle.SomeInfo;
```

This will trigger the `PropertyChanged` event, which will update your control's on the main window.

If you are not familiar with the MVVM (Model, View. View Model) pattern you can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks alot for the very quick response !